# Split logical vector based on FALSE/TRUE patterns

Tags: r, vector, split

Given logical vector `x`:

```
x <- c(FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, TRUE, TRUE, FALSE, FALSE, TRUE, FALSE, 
       FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, TRUE, TRUE, TRUE, FALSE, TRUE)
```

How to split `x` based on every `FALSE/TRUE` patterns? Of course, we can simply do the split based on `TRUE/FALSE` patterns using `!x`.

So the split would search for the patterns `FALSE, FALSE, ..., FALSE , TRUE, TRUE, ..., TRUE` until we reach again a `FALSE`. At which point, we stop. Said differently, we do the split every time we move from a `TRUE` to a `FALSE`.

Here is what I ended up with:

```
p <- which(diff(x)==-1)+1
split(x, cumsum(seq_along(x) %in% p))
```

So the output is rightly:

```
# $`0`
# [1] FALSE FALSE FALSE  TRUE  TRUE

# $`1`
# [1] FALSE FALSE  TRUE

# $`2`
# [1] FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE

# $`3`
# [1] FALSE  TRUE
```

Any other solution to this problem? More efficient way to do this?

Comment: Sorry. I really did not get what you want to do. How would the split work?

Comment: Try `split(x, cumsum(c(TRUE, diff(x) < 0)))`

Comment: Don't get if you are looking for a more efficient way of doing something or if you didn't get to your desired result (in which case, please specify it).

Comment: your explanation don't explain much. From your code you split your vector every time you move from `TRUE` to `FALSE`. Is that correct?

Comment: `split(x, with(rle(x), rep(cumsum(!values), lengths)))` is another option